# How to Disable transparent huge page in Golang Code?

Tags: go, operating-system, huge-pages

Is there a way for my processes not to use transparent huge page instead of just changing the configuration of the entire operating system(Linux)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like shown below. You should test thoroughly to ensure there are no ill interactions with the go runtime.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
    "syscall"
)

const (
    // https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/
    PRCTL_SYSCALL = 157

    // see /usr/include/linux/prctl.h
    PR_SET_THP_DISABLE = 41
    PR_GET_THP_DISABLE = 42
)

func disableTHP() {
    _, _, errno := syscall.RawSyscall6(uintptr(PRCTL_SYSCALL), uintptr(PR_SET_THP_DISABLE), uintptr(1), 0, 0, 0, 0)
    if errno != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("failed to disable THP: %v", errno)
    }
}
func isTHPDisabled() bool {
    s, _, errno := syscall.RawSyscall6(uintptr(PRCTL_SYSCALL), uintptr(PR_GET_THP_DISABLE), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    if errno != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("failed get THP disable status: %v", errno)
    }
    return s == 1
}

func main() {
    if os.Getenv("X_IN_CHILD_PROC") == "" {
        runtime.LockOSThread()
        disableTHP()
        cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], os.Args...)
        cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), fmt.Sprintf("X_IN_CHILD_PROC=yes"))
        cmd.Stdin, cmd.Stdout, cmd.Stderr = os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr
        _ = cmd.Run() // err discarded
        os.Exit(cmd.ProcessState.ExitCode())
    }

    // code below has THP disabled

    if !isTHPDisabled() { // sanity check
        log.Fatal("THP is somehow not disabled")
    }

    fmt.Println("THP is disabled")
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, it really helped. But I tried this example, and the results are as follows, the RES of the child process does decrease a lot, but the value of the parent process is still very high, do I have to use the child process for it to take effect?https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4r5T.png

Comment: Yes, you have to use the child process by putting you code after where I have the comment `// code below has THP disabled` in my code snippet above.